# How to write a test that renders a view? Will it error out if a route helper returns an error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Say my view pages have route helpers like:

```
root_url

user_edit_path
```

Now if I change things in routes.rb that effect these helpers, I want to make sure my unit tests capture this and report any errors that result of the syntax in my view pages.

Can rspec help with this, or is this a webrat functional test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rspec can help, with [routing specs](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/dir/routing-specs/access-to-named-routes-in-routing-specs)